# break content to new page after specific div in print window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am printing specific content using javascript.
Let me show you how i am printing it.

```
var data='many div and contents';
var html="<html>";
html+="<head>";
html+="<style> body{ font-family:'arial' } .tempcss{ margin:0 0 0 10px !important;  } .print_border{ border:1px solid #000; padding:0 20px; } </style>";
html+="</head>";
html+="<body>";
html+= data;
html+="</body>";
html+="</html>";

var printWin = window.open('','','left=0,top=0,fullscreen,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0');
printWin.document.write(html);
printWin.document.close();
printWin.focus();
printWin.print();
printWin.close();
```

So it will open new window with content with print option. 
It will showing ok on new window, but not splitting content properly in print.
What i want to do is, I want to add page break in print layout after specific div.

Like this,

```
<div class="test"></div>
<-- page break here  -->
<div class="test"></div>
<-- page break here  -->
<div class="test"></div>
<-- page break here  -->
```

So this way when i print page all div will show separately in each page.
I don't know how to do it. So please help me on this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: use css [break-after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after)

Comment: @Pete i tried but not working for me

Comment: You need to have something in the div as it won't work on empty elements

Comment: @Pete yes i have many other div and table also in live site. its just demo here that im showing here.

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://fiddle.jshell.net/khrrrf4n/3/show/light/

Answer (score 5):

How about using the [page-break-after property in CSS?](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/)

```
@media print {
  div.test {
    page-break-after: always;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

add CSS `display: block; page-break-before: always;`

```html
 <div style="display: block; page-break-before: always; ">
<!-- your new page content -->
</div>
```